# debug ASP.NET Core application in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

I created a new project in my solution. The project is ASP.NET Core application.

The problem is that When I click on IISExpress [image: iis express lounch button] to start debugging I have this error:

[image: error]

These are the project property Debug
[image: property1]

[image: property2]

I don't know what to do... Can someone help me?

---

EDIT
This is my launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8083/backendCore",
       "sslPort": 0
     },
    "iisExpress": {
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8083",
       "sslPort": 0
     }
 },
 "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
 "profiles": {
     "IIS Express": {
       "commandName": "IISExpress",
       "launchBrowser": true,
       "launchUrl": "backend",
       "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
       }
     },
     "backendCore": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
        "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
       },
       "prova": {
          "commandName": "IIS",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "launchUrl": "backend"
        }
       }
     }
```

and startup.cs

```
namespace backendCore
{
  public class Startup
  {
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
       Configuration = configuration;
     }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        services.AddControllers();
     }

     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
           app.UsePathBase("/backend"); //Add this line
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
           endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
     }
  }
}
```

this is the snippet of my controller (but the backend never stops here)

```
namespace backendCore.Controllers
{
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("api/Auth/{language}/guest")]
    [HttpPost]
    
    public ActionResult guestAuth(string language)
    {
       return Ok(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try without /backend in the url

Comment: already tryed but i got the same error

Comment: No matter what kind of ASP.NET Core project you created, it is not likely to handle `http://localhost:8083/backend`. Thus, 404 is expected. You have to study routing and learn what are the correct URLs expected by this web app.

Comment: I used the same Debug configuration as yours, but there is no abnormality on my side. Can you provide the code related to your controller?

Comment: I have more than 1 controller. it's not like it's some other configuration file?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your controller?

Comment: I saw in your `launchSettings.json` the sufix `backendCore`; the route sufix to be lauched is `backend` or `backendCore`?

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code in your `startup.cs` file `Configure` method

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UsePathBase("/backend"); //Add this line
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

This adds a middleware that extracts the specified path base from a request path and postpend it to the request path base. This is only for the development environment, if your production environment also has a *backend* sub-folder configured, put it outside the `if` condition.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a snippet from your `launchSettings.json` and `startup.cs` files. You will find `launchSettings.json` file inside the `Properties` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code. Hope work in your case!

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });
        }



 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UsePathBase("/backend"); //Add this line
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTTP POST vs GET

Your endpoint is a `[HttpPost]`, you can not enter the URL in a browser and navigate to it. Navigating to a URL in the browser is a GET request.

## Routing

You have shared the (partial) code for a controller and endpoint which is the following:

`[Route("api/Auth/{language}/guest")]`
Matches EXACTLY: `http://localhost:8083/api/Auth/{language}/guest`

Navigating to `http://localhost:8083/backend` will result in a 404, since it's not matching the exact path. Routing does not cover parts of the path.

## UsePathBase

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `UsePathBase`, that should only be necessary when working in a proxy scenario (eg; hosting with nginx or Apache), you haven't alluded to any requirement that would make using it necessary, so I would remove it, since it's just muddying the waters.

> For reference: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dealing-with-application-base-urls-and-razor-link-generation-while-hosting-aspnet-web-apps-behind-reverse-proxies

I'm sure this will generate more questions, so please edit your post appropriately and ask away.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear from your question exactly what you are trying to accomplish. But I'll try and bring some clarity.

In your `launchSettings.json` you specify that the launch URL should be `backend`:

```
"profiles": {
     "IIS Express": {
       "commandName": "IISExpress",
       "launchBrowser": true,
       "launchUrl": "backend",  // <----- Here you specify the launch URL
       "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
       }
     },
```

This means that when the application starts, it will start at the path `{base url}/backend` (in your case the `base url` is `http://localhost:8083`). Because you have also set the `launchBrowser` to `true`, the browser will also open when the application starts. When a browser opens a path it will send a HTTP GET request to that path. So when you start your application, the browser sends a GET request to the `{base url}/backend` route, but you have no controller handling that route, hence the HTTP Status code 404.

As Adam Vincent also mentions, you should also remove the call to `UsePathBase()` in your `Startup.cs`. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase) it:

> Adds a middleware that extracts the specified path base from request path and postpend it to the request path base.

I don't believe this brings you closer to what you are trying to accomplish.

Since your `guestAuth()` method in your `AuthController` is of a HTTP POST type, it will not be possible to hit that endpoint from a browser. I would suggest using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or similar software to develop and test your API. If you set a breakpoint in your `guestAuth()` method, start your application with debugging and then send a POST request from Postman to `{base url}/api/Auth/test/guest`, you should hit that breakpoint.